# asp.net ef code first duplicate elements with foreign key

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first

I have the following code :

```
    public Exam CreateExam(string name, List<Question> questions, DateTime timeNow)
    {
        User user = GetUserByName(name);

        Exam exam = new Exam()
        {
            Questions = questions,
            StartDate = timeNow,
            User = user
        };
        Context.Exams.Add(exam);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return exam;
    }
```

Exam :

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

And user has the basic user infos.

My problem is that when I create an exam for the user, the save change also add a new user to the database, with only the ID being different. How do I prevent that and make it understand that I want to link it to the existing user ?

Thank you !

Edit: GetUserByName() :

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("Select * from Users where name = @name", new SqlParameter("name", name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: what `GetUserByName` is doing? are you inserting `User` in this method.

Comment: I edited my post with the answer, but it's a simple select.

Comment: so what's your question, can you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `SqlQuery` to fetch user, he **will not be tracked** by Entity Framework, because you can write arbitrary query and map result to `User` class. So EF consider, that he is new one, when you reference to him. To fix this problem, you should manually attach his to context:

```
User user = GetUserByName(name);
Context.Users.Attach(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based [Slava Utesinov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543178/asp-net-ef-code-first-duplicate-elements-with-foreign-key/52585024#52585024) answer Entity Framework's change tracker does not track entity changes when get from raw query such as:

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("Select * from Users where name = @name", new SqlParameter("name", name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Therefore when you call SaveChanges() method, Entity Framework change tracker detect user entity state as **Added** (new entity)

1.you can use  [DbSet.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery) instead of [Database.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) because DbSet.SqlQuery will tracked by the context:

```
Context.Users.SqlQuery("Select * from Users where name = @name", new SqlParameter("name", name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

or 
2.you can attach entity to current context dbset as unchanged state